# Store data received from third parts in endpoint URL with PHP

Tags: php, api, endpoint

I'm trying to receive a data response from a third party API system to my URL endpoint with PHP. So the third parts is sending a post request to my endpoint(the url that I filled in in their API panel) whenever they have a new data response for me. Basically they are sending only the last response data when from their system they have a new submission. I have added this on my endpoint URL to see if I can see the data response received:

```
$request_data = file_get_contents('php://input');

var_dump($request_data);
```

On their panel I can test the endpoint url result and on their panel I have this result when I click on the **test request** button, which is basically the result of my `var_dump`:

[image: result in their API panel]

But on my side the output is like a full string but I don't get nothing on my side at my end point URL.

[image: my endpoint URL]

This is the `post_max_size` within my phpinfo file so my the $_POST variable shouldn't be empty:

[image]

The format of the submitted data that I should expect to receive to my URL endpoint is like below:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "",
        "name": "",
        "email": "",
        "phone": "",
        "description": "",
        "street": "",
        "housenumber": "",
        "postcode": "",
        "city": "",
        "questions": {
            "Type opdracht": "",
            "Wat wil je laten opstellen?": ""
        },
        "questions_unmapped": {
            "114": "",
            "187": ""
        },
        "date": "",
        "notes": ""
    }
}
```

Is there any way to:

- convert this string in a PHP object
- print/store those data on my side (my endpoint URL)

Comment: Have you checked if the $_POST variable contains any data?

Comment: array(0) { } on both the side with $_POST.

Comment: Okay, I would then 1) check the $_REQUEST variable to see if they sent the request with another HTTP method 2) check the PHP error log to see if there are any errors that might indicate another problem

Comment: Still get array(0) { } also with $_REQUEST.

Comment: What is your value of "post_max_size" ? You can check this by running "phpinfo();" command in your script. If it is set to 0 the $_POST variable will be empty.

Comment: @thephper post_max_size=8M so it's not empy.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide documentation of this third party API?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are receiving the request with a `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`,  you should be able to get the body of the request using:

```
$request_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Now, if you are receiving a `multipart/form-data` request and you can't modify the content-type of its body, you can try changing the following option in your php.ini (PHP 5.4+):

```
enable_post_data_reading = On
```

This will allow you to parse POST requests using php://input BUT, it will disable the automatic parsing of data on PHP internal arrays $_POST and even $_FILES. See more information about this option on the following page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.enable-post-data-reading

You can read why you can't ready the body of the request for `multipart/form-data` on the following page (look for: php://input): https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

After receiving the request, you can parse it in the following way (assuming is a JSON string, just like it looks like in the image you provided):

```
$jsonRequest = json_decode($requestBody, true);
```

*json_decode* documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1):

Try **$_POST** instance of file_get_contents('php://input');

Comment: I get array(0) { } on both the side with $_POST.

Answer (score 1):

I emulated your 3rd Party APIs posting with a Curl script as follows

```
$data_string = '{
"operacion": {
   "tok": "[generated token]",
   "shop_id": "12313",
   "respuesta": "S",
   "respuesta_details": "respuesta S",
   "extended_respuesta_description": "respuesta extendida",
   "moneda": "PYG",
   "monto": "10100.00",
   "authorization_number": "123456",
   "ticket_number": "123456789123456",
   "response_code": "00",
   "response_description": "Transacción aprobada.",
   "security_information": {
       "customer_ip": "123.123.123.123",
       "card_source": "I",
       "card_country": "Croacia",
       "version": "0.3",
       "risk_index": "0"
   }
}}';


$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/test/index.php');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

In my index.php I emulated your URL endpoint as follows

```
$request_data = file_get_contents('php://input');   
$decoded_params = json_decode($request_data,true);
var_dump($decoded_params);
```

And the output which I got is this.

```
Array
(
[operacion] => Array
    (
        [tok] => [generated token]
        [shop_id] => 12313
        [respuesta] => S
        [respuesta_details] => respuesta S
        [extended_respuesta_description] => respuesta extendida
        [moneda] => PYG
        [monto] => 10100.00
        [authorization_number] => 123456
        [ticket_number] => 123456789123456
        [response_code] => 00
        [response_description] => Transacción aprobada.
        [security_information] => Array
            (
                [customer_ip] => 123.123.123.123
                [card_source] => I
                [card_country] => Croacia
                [version] => 0.3
                [risk_index] => 0
            )

    )

)
```

I just made the following change to your endpoint code

> $decoded_params = json_decode($request_data); => $decoded_params = json_decode($request_data,true);

Answer (score 0):

Brother Ugol,

What I will do is, whenever someone send post request to our API(endpoint)

#### Solutions

### Method 1

1. Save the json into your database's tbl_input_json
2. Then, when admin access to the system, they could decide whether they want to insert those json record permanently into database's tables or not.

### Method 2

1. Directly, use json_decode to change the string into php array
2. Then, directly insert all these records into the database.

** Hope this solve your curiosity.